Importing custom font in nextjs react project not working properly
So I got this static html template which I'm currently converting into a next project using react, no typescript.
The current status of the project is a navigation bar, containing symbols from a single svg file on the far left, some text and logo in-between with animations and hyperlinks in the middle and a dark mode toggle on the far right which currently doesn't work. The text & logo part contains a dropdown, which is the problem.
It's either the dropdown contents clipping and the font working (overflow/scrollbar is visible and you're able to scroll) with the main tag in page.js, or the dropdown working but not the font when using the body tag.
I've also tried importing to global.css using @import and @font-family as well as a link in the header, but nothing seems to work. I'd need the body tag but then the font won't work, no matter what I do.
importing the font in layout.js - only works on main tag:
const rajdhani = Rajdhani({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
  variable: '--font-rajdhani',
  weight: ['400', '500', '700'],
});

function in layout.js - only works on main tag:
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" class="h-full overflow-x-hidden dark">
      <Header />
      <body className={rajdhani.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

console log output for the font:
{
  style: {
    fontFamily: "'__Rajdhani_dbf578', '__Rajdhani_Fallback_dbf578'",
    fontStyle: 'normal'
  },
  className: '__className_dbf578',
  variable: '__variable_dbf578'
}

page.js with Navbar containing all social icons (SocialSection.jsx), text+logo (MenuSection.jsx) and the theme toggler as ThemeToggle.jsx (see screenshots):
return (
    <body class="relative z-10 antialiased text-gray-500 text-sm h-full bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-x-hidden dark:text-gray lg:text-base">
      <div id="site-wrapper" class="flex flex-col h-full js-site-wrapper">
        <div class="header-wrapper text-white">
          <header id="site-header" class="text-white">
            <div class="mx-auto max-w-[1440px] px-5">
              <NavBar />
            </div>
          </header>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

result when using the main tag in page.js
result when using the body tag in page.js
As already stated, I've tried importing to layout.js via children, which works for the main tag in page.js but not when changing it to body, importing as a link in the header and last but not least in global.css.
I need the body tag to work, so the problem is the font not applying to anything. I got to the point where I could change the font in global.css, but it threw a random times new roman style on me.
